# Different Result with Class and Without Class

Tags: css

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<form method="get" action="#" class="test">
  <input type="search"/><input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

I get two different results if I use:

```
form { input { box-sizing: border-box; } }
```

See in http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/ksuJc

Or

```
form.test { input { box-sizing: border-box; } }
```

See in http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/zmgjF

See the right margin in the button? No? Try with Chrome, IE and Safari ...

Only in Firefox there is no difference ...

What am I missing?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: How did you use the `css` not the `pseudo` code, the original `css`.

Comment: Just reformulated the question and added online examples ... Check it out in Chrome, IE or Safari ... In Firefox there is no difference.

Comment: What? using form input { } or form.test input { } should be the same ... since the form has the class test. So in both cases I am applying box-sizing: border-box to the inputs inside the form ... Not?

Comment: Try removing the CSS normalizing code from both examples and then they are both identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the one example you have this:

```
form.test input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

In the other example

```
form input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

In the second version `input[type="search"]` has more specificity so it overrides anything declared in `form input`

In the first version `form.test input` has more specificity, so it takes precedence.